# How to map Angular2's templateUrl to get views from another server?

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm hosting an angular 2 app on Server A. It works fine on Server A because all the files are where they should be. On Server B, the company is putting an iframe in a document that will load a page who's references all point toward my app in hopes of putting my app in a subsection of the page.

I'm running into issues about where Server B requests my imports and views from. On Server A I have a very simple System.config:

```
System.config({
 packages: {
   'scripts': {
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
 }
});
System.import('scripts/boot');
```

In order to load scripts from Server B, it was changed to:

```
System.config({
 packages: {
   'scripts': {
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
 },
 map: {
   scripts: 'http://ServerB/scripts'
 }
});
System.import('scripts/boot');
```

This will successfully load my boot.js and other js files all the way up until a component requests a view. My main view has this for a Component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'views/nav.html'
})
```

This will request `http://ServerA/views/nav.html` but I'd like it to get the view from the same path on Server B.

I know this whole iframe business requesting a PHP page and not my actual site is inefficient and problematic but it's out of my control. The iframe will receive a different index.html than my normal site so I can give it a different SystemJS config and direct it to a different boot file but after that it requests all the same files as my app on Server A would request.

Without going through and updating all my `templateUrl`s to fully qualified names, is there a way I can route all the requests that grab requests to a different path?

I've tried this config but it didn't work:

```
System.config({
 packages: {
   'scripts': {
     defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
 },
 map: {
   scripts: 'http://ServerB/scripts',
   views: 'http://ServerB/views'
 }
});
System.import('scripts/boot');
```